# python constantly updating a global variable in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, rfid

i'm using this library to handle a PN5180 rfid reader:

https://github.com/fservida/pyPN5180

for what i understand in consist in one function named inventory() that return a list of up to 16 detected cards. you put it in a loop in order for it to update

i'd like to be able to test how many cards are in the list at various times as well as returning some ids

so i've tried putting the looped function into to a thread but i don't know ho to update it as a global variable in order to do my tests in the main program.

```
def ListeningCards():

    print("listening to card thread started")
    while True:
        global cards    
        cards = PN5180().inventory()
        cardcount = len(cards)

th1 = threading.Thread(target = ListeningCards)

th1.start()


#main progam:

while true
#etc
```

so how can i achieve constant listening of the rfid chip and returning it in my main programme? i tried multithreading but maybe there's other ways?

Answer (score 1):

`cards` is undefined until the first time the loop of `ListeningCards` is run.  It may take a few milliseconds for the program to start running.  If your main program accesses `cards` before `ListeningCards` has had a chance to set it the first time, then you will get an undefined variable.

You might just want to set `cards = 0` at the top of your program, or something like that, so that it has a default value.

Comment: Ok thanks, don't have the error anymore. For the rest, cards isn't updating in the main program

Comment: I know nothing about `PN5180().inventory()`.  Are you sure you don't just want create a single `PN5180()` object and repeatedly call its inventory method?  Is there a way you can get the device to give you a callback when something has changed, rather that you repeatedly pinging it?

Comment: Also, its constructor takes a debug argument.  That may either help you, or overwhelm you with output.

Comment: I might not be sufficiently skill to tell, but there is only the method inventory () in the library and I don't think it is designed to do callbacks as it is. I hoped I could divert it without divin too deep in it. But it would be better if I knew how to do it that's for sure

Comment: But there's no such thing as shortcuts! I'll take a look at how callback works and try to tweak the library a bit